# How to add a command delay using the 'on_message' event - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using a

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
```

for my commands in my discord bot, is there a way I can add a delay between command use. For example a 5s delay between using a command, if a user attempts to use the command during the cool down, the bot will send them a message saying how long of a delay is left. And if possible, could there be an individual delay for each command?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This comes down to either having a huge json file, a large SQL database or a dictionary in memory, saving the cooldown of each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`commands.cooldown`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.cooldown) to implement a cooldown:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@commands.cooldown(rate=1, per=5, type=commands.BucketType.user)
@bot.command()
async def example(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Command received ")

bot.run("token")
```